# Import java library to swift project for OS X

Tags: java, objective-c, swift, macos

Is it possible to import java classes from .java files to a swift project for OS X?

Answer (score 0):

Not directly. You can run JVM in your process and invoke your library using JNI. But I can't explain how to do it in few sentences.

Comment: Thank you. Any link with some details for the process?

Comment: It also depends on the type if library and your use case.